# import of node module failing using next.js with typescript

Tags: typescript, next.js, npm-install, typescript-module-resolution

I'm trying to use a package, brypt, I've installed in project using npm install bcrypt.

I can see the package in node_modules folder but when attempt to import in my code I receive error:
"*Cannot find module 'bcryptjs' or its corresponding type declarations.*"

I've tried amending the moduleResolution value in tsconfig.json as thought this may be my issue but still a problem. Can anyone see/guide me, as to what I am doing wrong here?

This is content of my tsconfig.json file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "next"
      }
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "./*"
      ]
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "next-env.d.ts",
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx",
    ".next/types/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

and this is where I'm trying to use method:

```
import { IUserAuthenticatedResponse } from "@/types/userAccountTypes";
import axios from "axios";
import bcrypt from 'bcryptjs';

export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic' // defaults to auto
export async function POST(request: Request) {
    const body = await request.json();
    const { emailAddress, password } = body;

    async function authenticateUser(cancel = false): Promise<IUserAuthenticatedResponse[]> {
        const salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10)
        const response = await api.request({
            url: process.env.apiBaseUrl + 'authenticateUserAccount/' + emailAddress + "/" + password,
            method: "GET",
            // retrieving the signal value by using the property name
            signal: cancel ? cancelApiObject[this.get.name].handleRequestCancellation().signal : undefined,
        })
        return response.data
    }
}
```

Thanks for any assitance you can offer.

Comment: Idk if this will be helpful to you or not but sometimes the issue is IDE just restart your ide/restart your server. If the issue still exist it might be ts acting up due to other error in your program.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why but seems I had to install using following:

```
npm i --save-dev @types/bcrypt
```